# html5 draggable - arbitrary drop position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

All the examples that I've seen with draggable elements have a specific destination where the draggable element can be dropped. Is it possible to drop the element anywhere on the screen without specifying the destinations?

I have a map (ThinkGeo) with some specific areas coming from the database. when the user clicks/touches those areas, I'm showing popups with description of those areas. The popup is nothing else than a div that I'm showing and hiding accordingly.

The user wants to be able to move around the popup div on the map. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly possible and pretty easy with jQuery UI:

```
$("#elementId").draggable();
```

And a shim for touch events:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/ which at 584 bytes, is pretty lightweight.

Comment: That's the same as adding draggable="true" to an element. I want to move the element to get it out of my way when viewing the map, so setting specific drop zones will not work here..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you fully yet. Draggable through jQueryUI is not dependent on having somewhere to drop it. It is simply the ability to move it wherever you like. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ what does that not give you that you need?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't support touch events.

Comment: Updated above to include touch shim.